# Can LibTIFF be used with C++ to get the float values of images?

Tags: c++, floating-point, tiff, libtiff, image-conversion

I read [here](http://maptools-org.996276.n3.nabble.com/Floating-Point-Tiff-Format-td1967.html) that LibTIFF can display floating point TIFFs. However, I would like to load an image, then get the float values as an array.

Is this possible to do using LibTIFF?

[Example TIFF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f15fkkj5dg5ojzt/map.tif?dl=0)

EDIT: I am using RHEL 6.

Comment: You can use `Dropbox` to share a link to a TIFF, or the Microsoft thing `OneDrive` or `Imgur` or somesuch.

Comment: As regards viewers, you could try `gimp`, `feh` or `display` which is part of ImageMagick.

Comment: Your sample image is an 8-bit image, not float?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it with pure *libTIFF*, your code might look something like this - note that I have not done much error checking so as not to confuse the reader of the code - but you should check that the image is of type float, and you should check the results of memory allocations and you probably shouldn't use `malloc()` like I do but rather the new C++ methods of memory allocation - but the concept is hopefully clear and the code generates the same answers as my `CImg` version...

```
#include "tiffio.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

  TIFF* tiff = TIFFOpen("image.tif","r");
  if (!tiff) {
    cerr << "Failed to open image" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  uint32 width, height;
  tsize_t scanlength;

  // Read dimensions of image
  if (TIFFGetField(tiff,TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH,&width) != 1) {
    cerr << "Failed to read width" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  if (TIFFGetField(tiff,TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, &height) != 1) {
    cerr << "Failed to read height" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  scanlength = TIFFScanlineSize(tiff);

  // Make space for image in memory
  float** image= (float**)malloc(sizeof (float*)*height);

  cout << "Dimensions: " << width << "x" << height << endl;
  cout << "Line buffer length (bytes): " << scanlength << endl;

  // Read image data allocating space for each line as we get it
  for (uint32 y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    image[y]=(float*)malloc(scanlength);
    TIFFReadScanline(tiff,image[y],y);
    cout << "Line(" << y << "): " << image[y][0] << "," << image[y][1] << "," << image[y][2] << endl;
  }
  TIFFClose(tiff);

}
```

**Sample Output**

```
Dimensions: 512x256
Line buffer length (bytes): 6144
Line(0): 3.91318e-06,0.232721,128
Line(1): 0.24209,1.06866,128
Line(2): 0.185419,2.45852,128
Line(3): 0.141297,3.06488,128
Line(4): 0.346642,4.35358,128
...
...
```

By the way...

I converted your image to a regular JPEG using `ImageMagick` in the Terminal at the command line as follows:

```
convert map.tif[0] -auto-level result.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for all of your solutions! I think that this may work. I do have a quick question first though: how can I just view a TIFF image first? I've been reading the documentation but am only finding things to get data rather than just view an image. As a side note, I am using LibGeoTIFF.

Comment: Pleasure! It would help a lot if you could supply a sample image please, and also say what Operating System you use.

Comment: When you say the new methods of allocation, do you mean like       `float** image = new float*[height];`
`for(int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
       image[i] = new float[width];`  this?

Comment: Yes :-) I'm an old `C` dog, rather than a new, fangled `C++` cool kid!

Comment: Haha thanks! :) Sorry for all of the follow-up questions, but how would the for loop then change without using malloc? Also, for the cout statement within the for loop, why do you only print y[0], y[1], and y[2]?

Comment: Just as you showed in your previous comment. I only print the first few values because I have no idea what you want to do with them - you only said you wanted to load them into an array - not what happens after that.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I meant: instead of saying `image[y]=(float*)malloc(scanlength);`, how would I set the whole row of a 2D array?

Comment: @MarkSetchell do you happen to have any experience in reading TIFFs by hand?

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you will have a much easier time with this if you use the OpenCV library.

If you have OpenCV library compiled and installed doing what you are asking is as easy as using the [imread()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#cv2.imread) function. This saves it to an object called cv::Mat (aka a matrix) with the same dimensions and values as the tiff.

From there you can do just about anything you want with it.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do it with LibTIFF, and I may well add an answer based on that later, but for ease of installation and use, I would look at `CImg` which is a C++ **header-only** library that is very powerful and ideal for your purposes. As it is header-only, it is simple to include (just one file) and needs no special linking or building.

Here is how you might read a TIFF of RGB floats:

```
#define cimg_display 0
#define cimg_use_tiff
#include "CImg.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cimg_library;
using namespace std;

int main(){

   // Read in an image
   CImg <float>img("image.tif");

   // Get its width and height and tell user
   int w=img.width();
   int h=img.height();
   cout << "Dimensions: " << w << "x" << h << endl;

   // Get pointer to buffer/array of floats
   float* buffer = img.data();

   cout << buffer[0] << "," << buffer[1] << "," << buffer[2] << endl; 
}
```

That prints the first three red pixels because they are arranged in planes - i.e. all the red pixels first, then all the green pixel then all the blue pixels.

You would compile that with:

```
g++-6 -std=c++11 read.cpp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -ltiff -o read
```

If you prefer, you can access the pixels a slightly different way like this:

```
#define cimg_display 0
#define cimg_use_tiff
#include "CImg.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cimg_library;
using namespace std;

int main(){

   // Read in an image
   CImg <float>img("image.tif");

   // Get its width and height and tell user
   int w=img.width();
   int h=img.height();
   cout << "Dimensions: " << w << "x" << h << endl;

   // Dump the pixels
   for(int y=0;y<h;y++)
      for(int x=0;x<w;x++)
          cout << x << "," << y << ": "
               << img(x,y,0,0) << "/" 
               << img(x,y,0,1) << "/" 
               << img(x,y,0,2) << endl;

}
```

**Sample Output**

```
Dimensions: 512x256
0,0: 3.91318e-06/0.232721/128
1,0: 1.06577/0.342173/128
2,0: 2.3778/0.405881/128
3,0: 3.22933/0.137184/128
4,0: 4.26638/0.152943/128
5,0: 5.10948/0.00773837/128
6,0: 6.02352/0.058757/128
7,0: 7.33943/0.02835/128
8,0: 8.33965/0.478541/128
9,0: 9.46735/0.335981/128
10,0: 10.1918/0.340277/128
...
...
```

For your information, I made the test image file also with `CImg` like this - basically each red pixel is set to its x-coordinate plus a small random float less than 0.5. each green pixel is set to its y-coordinate plus a small random float less than 0.5 and each blue pixel is set to a mid-tone.

```
#define cimg_display 0
#define cimg_use_tiff
#define cimg_use_png
#include "CImg.h"
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace cimg_library;

int main(){
   const int w=512;
   const int h=256;
   const int channels=3;
   float* buffer = new float[w*h*channels];
   float* fp=buffer;
   for(int y=0;y<h;y++){
      for(int x=0;x<w;x++){
         *fp++=x+float(rand())/(2.0*RAND_MAX);    // red
      }
   }
   for(int y=0;y<h;y++){
      for(int x=0;x<w;x++){
         *fp++=y+float(rand())/(2.0*RAND_MAX);    // green
      }
   }
   for(int y=0;y<h;y++){
      for(int x=0;x<w;x++){
         *fp++=128;    // blue
      }
   }

   CImg <float>img(buffer,w,h,1,channels);
   img.save_tiff("result.tif");
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yet another, easily installed, lightweight option would be to use `vips`. You can convert your 32-bit TIF to a raw file of 32-bit floats and read them straight into your C++ program. At the commandline, do the conversion with

```
vips rawsave yourImage.tif raw.bin
```

and then read in the uncompressed, unformatted floats from file `raw.bin`. If we now dump the file `raw.bin`, interpreting the data as floats, you can see the same values as in my other answers:

```
od -f raw.bin

0000000     3.913185e-06    2.327210e-01    1.280000e+02    1.065769e+00
0000020     3.421732e-01    1.280000e+02    2.377803e+00    4.058807e-01
0000040     1.280000e+02    3.229325e+00    1.371841e-01    1.280000e+02
```

Of course, you can have your program do the conversion by linking to `libvips` or simply using `system()` to run the commandline version and then read its output file.